# SQL help with omitting records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that is returning multiple records, these records come in pairs. Some of the info in the record pair columns is the same, ex ID and year, but other info has different values, ex column named type may be null on one and 'A' on another.

If this third column type is equal to 'A' or another arbitrary string for one of the pairs, how do I go about having it exclude both records with the same id and year in the WHERE section of the SQL query? I was thinking a case statement may be used but I'm not sure.

Comment: yes, you can use case and just filter by distinct at the end, if you provide some sample we can give you more precise answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NOT EXISTS and a subquery...

```
SELECT id, year
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table t2 
                  WHERE ThirdColumn = 'A'
                  AND t2.id = t.id
                  AND t2.year = t.year)
```

Comment: that will result (2) table scans, not very optimal solution

Comment: There can be more than 2 of the same IDs, say there can be 8, but there will only be 2 of the same returned for each year, so each year has 2 ids that are the same. If I do just this then all the other IDs for other years will not be returned either, how can I do this with both the year and ID included? I'm going to need to port this to crystal syntax but for now just getting the SQL query down will get me started.

Comment: @ K Ivanov - If he doesn't have indexes on these fields then there are larger issues...

Comment: @Nard Dog - This is a simplified version of the logic you can use.  I'll add a multi-field version

Comment: @Nard Dog - edited to use NOT EXISTS which should be more performant.

Comment: @K I, @JNK This removes a record with ThirdColumn='A' even if it does not form a pair

Comment: @Richard - from the OP it sounds like he wants to exclude all records with a matching ID for the third column value, whether it is 1 record or 4.

Comment: "Pair" appears 3 times, followed by "both". I read it differently

Comment: I apologize for not being clear as I'm still learning. Here is an example. In this example it returns 8 different rows. I call them pairs because it is the same ID, but really they are just related rows returned because of joins etc. In this example, I would want both records from the first set to be excluded, there will only ever be one "pair" of IDs per year.
1st set:    ID: 234 Year:2004 Type:'A'
           ID: 234 Year:2004 Type: Null
2nd set:  ID: 234 Year:2005 Type:'C'
           ID: 234 Year:2005 Type: Null
3rd Set:   ID: 235 Year:2008 Type:'B'
           ID: 235 Year:2008 Type: Null

Comment: @Nard Dog - as long as you don't have single "orphan" rows without a paired row that you are worried about not selecting, the above query will work for that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Not so straightforward.

```
select t.*
from tbl t
left join (
  select t2.id, t2.year
  from tbl t2
  group by t2.id, t2.year
  having count(*) > 1 and
      count(case when type='A' then 1 end) *
      count(case when type='A' then null else 1 end) > 0
) X
  on X.id = t.id and X.year = t.year
WHERE X.id is null
```

- `count(*) > 1` helps us consider where there is at least a pair with the same id/year
- The 2 `count(case..) > 0`s determine that "at least one of the `type`s is 'A', and at least one is not
- `LEFT JOIN + WHERE IS NULL` is a classic technique to show only data where the left join failed, i.e. id/year pairs meeting the conditions of the subquery are taken out